# Selenium Chrome does not add extensions and arguments

Tags: c#, selenium

It looks like Selenium doesn't apply any options to the new browser instance, since neither the extension nor the arguments that were defined in code are applied, it just launches a regular Chrome window without extensions, with an infobar and no incognito mode

```
void ChromeSession()
    {
        const string siteUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
        options.AddArgument("--incognito");
        options.AddExtension(@"C:\Users\kiespetch1\Downloads\Solver.crx");

        new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Url = siteUrl;
    }
```

How I can add extensions and launch arguments?

Answer (score -1):

You can add profiles

```
options.AddArgument = ("user-data-dir':'/Users/Application/Chrome/Default'}
```

Comment: How does this fix the OP's problem? Can you expand your answer to explain why?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed after adding the argument with adding a specific profile in which the extension is already installed and configured if that's what are you trying to say